# How to get content from nested mark using PHP with regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

Here is the string:

```
$text = "aaaaaaaa[[Image:1939.jpg||thumb|right|200px|[[1939]], [[Mr. X]] is [[here]].]]bbb";
```

I wanna get this:

```
Image:1939.jpg||thumb|right|200px|[[1939]]，[[Mr. X]] is [[here]].
```

It's a mediawiki mark format. one article has one or more image mark.

My code:

```
$pattern = "/\[\[Image:([\s\S]*?)\]\]/";

preg_match($pattern, $text, $match);
```

But i got

```
Image:1939.jpg||thumb|right|200px|[[1939
```

Please help!

Comment: `trim($string, '[]');` :)

Comment: You'll need both ^ to mark the start of the string and $ to mark the end of the string.

Comment: sorry, the string isn't begin with "[[" and end with "]]". there are more chars.
i've edit the question.

Comment: What are yoou trying to achieve? I suspect you should instead use the MediaWiki web API. Inventing your own parser of MediaWiki markup is NEVER a good idea. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a recursive pattern:

```
$pattern = '~\[\[((?>[^[\]]++|(?R))*+)]]~';
$subject = 'aaaaaaaa[[Image:1939.jpg||thumb|right|200px|[[1939]], [[Mr. X]] is [[here]].]]bbb';

preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($match[1], true);
```

explanation:

```
$pattern =
  '~               # delimiter of the pattern
   \[\[            # the two open square brackets
   (               # first capture group
     (?>           # atomic group
         [^[\]]++  # all chars except square brackets 1 or more time
       |           # OR
         (?R)      # recurse the whole pattern
     )*+           # end of atomic group 0 or more time (allow void brackets)
   )               # end of capture group
   ]]              # the two closing square brackets
   ~x';            // delimiter with the x modifier that allow comments
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "[[Image:1939.jpg||thumb|right|200px|[[1939]]，[[Mr. X]] is [[here]].]]";
$pattern = '/\[\[(.*)\]\]/';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: sorry, the string isn't end with "]]". there are more chars.

Answer (score 0):

try this with your all conditions

```
$text = "aaaadsfasdfaaaa[[Image:1939.jpg||thumb|right|200px|[[1939]]，[[Mr. X]] is [[here]].]]bbbbdwebadfa";
$pattern = "/^[^.]+\[\[(.*)\]\]+[^.]+$/";
preg_match($pattern, $text, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work. It's a mediawiki mark format. one article has one or more image mark.

Comment: you mean like ;

`$text = "aaaadsfasdfaaaa[[Image:1939.jpg||thumb|right|200px|[[1939]]，[[Mr. X]] is [[here]].]]bbbbdwebadfaaaaadsfasdfaaaa[[Image:1939.jpg||thumb|right|200px|[[1939]]，[[Mr. X]] is [[here]].]]bbbbdwebadfa"` ?